# Ask for explanation for $ || X \beta ||^2 := \beta^T \Sigma \beta$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We consider n i.i.d. observations from the structural equation model. We denote by $X := (X_1,...,X_p)$ the $n \times p$ data matrix with n i.i.d. rows, each of them being $N(0, \Sigma)$-distributed, where $\Sigma$ is a nonsingular covariance matrix. The relations between the variables in a row can be represented as

$$X=XB + E,$$

where $B:= (\beta_{k,j})$ is a $p \times p$ matrix with $\beta_{j,j} =0$ for all j, and where E as an $n \times p$ matrix of independent noise vectors $E:=(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_p)$. Furthermore, E has n i.i.d rows which are $N(0, \Omega)$-distributed, with $\Omega := \text{diag} (|\omega_1|^2,...,|\omega_p|^2 ) $ a $p \times p$ diagonal matrix.

The above model can be written as

$$X_j = X \beta_j + \epsilon_j, j=1,...,p,$$

with $\beta_j$ the $j$th column of $B$. Then for any vector $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p$,

$$|| X \beta ||^2 := \beta^T \Sigma \beta$$.

I don't know how to get $|| X \beta ||^2 := \beta^T \Sigma \beta$. And what does that mean?

**I also add some other things from the paper:**

$$|| X \beta ||^2_n := \beta^T \Sigma_n \beta$$.

where $\Sigma_n := X^T X/n$ is the empirical covariance matrix based on the observations (data matrix) X.

For a permutation of $\pi$ of {1,...,p}, which plays the role of an order of the variables, we can rewrite B as a lower-diagonal matrix. Then the authors use Gram-Schmidt orthogonzalization.

Comment: $X=XB+E$, isn't that circular?

Comment: Note that $\lvert A\vec x\rVert_2^2 = \vec x^t A^tA\vec x$ is an identity that holds at the level of linear algebra, so if one can naively say that $\Sigma := X^t X$ your question reduces to the above linear algebra. I imagine that there is some additional (omitted) notation/context which means this isn't the answer you want though.

Comment: Expanding on what Mark said, it _is_ true that $\mathbb{E}[X^\top X] = n \Sigma$ (show this), so $\mathbb{E}[ \|X\beta\|^2] = n \beta^\top \Sigma \beta$, but the  precise statement you're writing probably has some elision (and is probably also missing some normalisation).

Comment: @Andrew Well it's just a linear equation. Usually though to get an SEM, you need  to ensure that the directed graph on $[1:p]$ formed by $\{i\to j\} \in E \iff \beta_{j,i} \neq 0$ is cycle free, which quite literally deals with the circularity issue (and concretely posits a causal generative structure).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Can you tell me why $E[X^T X]= n \Sigma$? Also, you might be right. In the paper, after some permutation, B can become a lower-diagonal matrix. Then the paper uses Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I add something in the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Jackie which paper are you referring to ?